# message 'The Distributor has not been installed correctly'

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I get the message

> The Distributor has not been installed correctly
> Could not enable database for publishing

when trying to execute `sp_replicationdboption`.  The publisher (which is on separate server from distributor) is shown correctly when I run
`EXEC sp_helpdistpublisher` but if I run `sp_get_distributor` from the publisher all fields are null

Comment: Thanks it is working now, not sure what changed so that it now works

Answer (score 0):

First you make sure you connect to your distributor server  with [server\instance]
from you publisher server.
Also you need to set up all the replication accounts and make sure [they have the right permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/95819/22336)
**and** you need to [create the distribution database in your distributor_server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/configure-publishing-and-distribution?view=sql-server-ver16)

there is this script as an example:

```
-- This script uses sqlcmd scripting variables. They are in the form
-- $(MyVariable). For information about how to use scripting variables  
-- on the command line and in SQL Server Management Studio, see the 
-- "Executing Replication Scripts" section in the topic
-- "Programming Replication Using System Stored Procedures".

-- Install the Distributor and the distribution database.
DECLARE @distributor AS sysname;
DECLARE @distributionDB AS sysname;
DECLARE @publisher AS sysname;
DECLARE @directory AS nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @publicationDB AS sysname;
-- Specify the Distributor name.
SET @distributor = $(DistPubServer);
-- Specify the distribution database.
SET @distributionDB = N'distribution';
-- Specify the Publisher name.
SET @publisher = $(DistPubServer);
-- Specify the replication working directory.
SET @directory = N'\\' + $(DistPubServer) + '\repldata';
-- Specify the publication database.
SET @publicationDB = N'AdventureWorks2012'; 

-- Install the server MYDISTPUB as a Distributor using the defaults,
-- including autogenerating the distributor password.
USE master
EXEC sp_adddistributor @distributor = @distributor;

-- Create a new distribution database using the defaults, including
-- using Windows Authentication.
USE master
EXEC sp_adddistributiondb @database = @distributionDB, 
    @security_mode = 1;
GO

-- Create a Publisher and enable AdventureWorks2012 for replication.
-- Add MYDISTPUB as a publisher with MYDISTPUB as a local distributor
-- and use Windows Authentication.
DECLARE @distributionDB AS sysname;
DECLARE @publisher AS sysname;
-- Specify the distribution database.
SET @distributionDB = N'distribution';
-- Specify the Publisher name.
SET @publisher = $(DistPubServer);

USE [distribution]
EXEC sp_adddistpublisher @publisher=@publisher, 
    @distribution_db=@distributionDB, 
    @security_mode = 1;
GO
```

You can also have a look at the way I got it done: [call the procedure sp_adddistpublisher as shown here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/182722/22336).